# Local notification app crashes simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm using the local notification plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/) with ng-cordova for an ionic poject:

This is my controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
    $scope.addNotification = function() {
        $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
            id: 'some_notification_id'
                // parameter documentation:
                // https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#further-informations-1
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('callback for adding background notification');
        });
    };
    $scope.checkIfIsTriggered = function() {
        $cordovaLocalNotification.isTriggered('some_notification_id').then(
            function(isTriggered) {
                alert('isTriggered');
            });
    };
})
```

I have a button on the default view which is loaded when the app starts with a ng-click, like so:

```
  <button ng-click="addNotification();" class="button button-stable">button-stable</button>
```

But when I run the app in the emulator and tap the button, the app crashes with the followiing error message:

```
: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-     [__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a840850'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x002cc1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x023848e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2 CoreFoundation 0x00369243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3 CoreFoundation 0x002bc50b forwarding + 1019
4 CoreFoundation 0x002bc0ee CFforwarding_prep_0 + 14
5 new 0x0011f917 -[APPLocalNotification notificationWithId:] + 503
6 new 0x0011f6a6 -[APPLocalNotification isNotificationScheduledWithId:] + 86
7 new 0x0011bccf __28-[APPLocalNotification add:]blockinvoke + 207
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x0293d7b8 dispatchcall_block_and_release + 15
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x029524d0 dispatchclient_callout + 14
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x02940eb7 dispatchroot_queue_drain + 291
 11 libdispatch.dylib 0x02941127 dispatchworker_thread2 + 39
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x02c89dab pthreadwqthread + 336
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x02c8dcce start_wqthread + 30
)
 Oct 19 11:54:21 xxxx-MacBook-Air.local backboardd[27466] : Application    'UIKitApplication:com.ionicframework.new903016[0xde04]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6"
```

Has anyone got it to work following the ng-cordova docs, or is there another approach I should be trying.

Thank's!

Comment: what is Cordova version do you use? If you have older then 3.5.0 - install new one

Comment: Hi, I'm using 4.0. I'm trying it now in ios8 (before ios7), and the app doesn't crash anymore (even though it is not working). I'll keep digging. Thank's!

Comment: I had similiar issue with cordova 4.1.2, @werbelow answer helped me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're still having this issue, I ran into this today as well.

Go into the plugin code, APPLocalNotifications.m in Xcode and change this line, towards the bottom:

`NSString* notId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]
                           stringValue];`

and replace it with this:

`NSString* notId = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];`

This worked for me today.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Perhaps log an issue on the plugin site, or do a pull request for the fix?

Comment: @werbelow where did you change this? I have updated the file  /plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/APPLocalNotification.m  however when i run the app on my phone via xcode the same error appears and the line of code shows unchanged in the debugger.

Comment: @Will I changed this in xcode under Plugins -> APPLocalNotification.m on line 514. Not sure it will be the same line number but it is under the comment that says Retrieves the local notification by its ID. Hope that helps.

Comment: @werbelow  - it did, thank you. after a lot of chasing my tail with this, some other bugs and ngcordova plugin issues i finally got a response form notifications.  yay.

Comment: @Will awesome, glad to hear it!