# Local Notifications with IonicFramework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a form where a user can tick which days and what time to set off an alarm. The form saves it's settings.

I want to now add a local notifications to fire as per the settings. I have used the ngCordova plugin to do this. The code does not raise an error, but I can't get a notification to fire.

This is what my controller looks like.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DailyCtrl', function($scope, $location, Settings,  $cordovaLocalNotification) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.settings = Settings.all();
  $scope.doSave = function() {
      Settings.save($scope.data.settings);
      var today = new Date();
      //save notification
       $scope.addNotification = function () {            
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaLocalNotification.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
          $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
            id: 'happi_alert',                
            date:       new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 16, 33, 0),    
            message:    "Happi App Message",  // The message that is displayed
            title:      "HappiApp Alert",  // The title of the message          
            sound:      "beep.caf",  // plays `beep.mp3` located in folder 
            //json:       String,  // Data to be passed through the notification
            repeat:     "minutely",  
            autoCancel: true,          
          }).then(function () {
            console.log('callback for adding background notification');
          }); 
        });  
        $cordovaLocalNotification.getScheduledIds(function (scheduledIds) {
          alert('Scheduled IDs: ' + scheduledIds.join(' ,'));
        }, scope);              
      };
      $location.path("/");
  };
})
```

How can i start to debug this? Where might I be going wrong?

I have tried running the immediate notification directly in a controller like this

```
.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope,  $cordovaLocalNotification) {
  $cordovaLocalNotification.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
})
```

However that crashes the emulator app with the following stack trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined
    at Object.add (ng-cordova.js:2979)
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:43)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:11591)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:11602)
    at $get (ionic.bundle.js:14906)
    at ionic.bundle.js:14295
    at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:7957)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14282)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:13730)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14330)
```

UPDATE

i have tried adding the notification directly using the window.plugin like this:

```
 window.plugin.notification.local.add({ 
      id: 'MYLN',     
      message: "this is a notification"
    });
```

but i get an error:

```
2014-12-29 12:31:40.051 HappiCards[32779:1207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7899dd00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x001e11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x020998e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0027e243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x001d150b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x001d10ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   HappiCards                          0x000f7387 -[APPLocalNotification notificationWithId:] + 503
    6   HappiCards                          0x000f7116 -[APPLocalNotification isNotificationScheduledWithId:] + 86
    7   HappiCards                          0x000f373f __28-[APPLocalNotification add:]_block_invoke + 207
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0266f7b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x026844d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02672eb7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 291
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02673127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x029d0dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x029d4cce start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

UPDATE:  I have deployed this app to a real device & get the same error -

```
[NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance o
```

on line

```
double timestamp = [[options objectForKey:@"date"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: I worry that this plugin isn't compatible with the emulator. Have you tried the app on a physical device?

Comment: What happens when you JUST try to run the "Great App!" immediate notification? I would also try to run that outside the nested functions. Getting that to work will be a good stepping stone to iterate off of.

Comment: thanks @Adam i have tried adding the notification directly into a controller & updated the post with details.

Comment: other users have same issues, awaiting update https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/312

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the update, Will. Some of the resources I'm finding online speak to NOT using ngCordova, but rather calling the actual plugin. Here are a list of things to try (fingers crossed):

1. Call a function (from ngCordova's [docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/), first example):

   ```
   .controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope,  $cordovaLocalNotification) {
     $scope.addMessage = function() {
       $cordovaLocalNotification.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
     };
   });
   ```
2. Use the plugin, not `$cordovaLocalNotification`, from this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngcordova-local-notification-plugin/10534):

   ```
   // Also need to expose window.plugin.not... in config, see link

   $scope.addNotification = function(tit, msg) {
     window.plugin.notification.local.add({
         id: 'MYLN',
         title:   tit,
         message: msg,
         icon: 'ic_notification',
         smallIcon: 'ic_notification_small'
     });
   };
   ```
3. Change the plugin code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450016/local-notification-app-crashes-simulator):

[image: Replace plugin code screen shot]

4. Try to use a `run` block from this [(non-successful) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856876/typeerror-cannot-read-property-notification-of-undefined):

   ```
   angular.module("starter", ['ionic'])
     .run(function($rootScope, $location, $ionicPlatform, $state) {
         $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
         $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
             id: '1',
             message: "Push!!"
         })
     }, false);  
   });
   ```
5. (All else has failed) Submit an issue with ngCordova. Here is a link for current issues open with [$cordovaLocalNotifications](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%24cordovaLocalNotification).

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Adam , Ill work through these and report back how it's coming along.  I got the ionic view app to load my app to help testing.  Hopefully ill get there!

Comment: Hey, @Will, any luck?

Comment: No none at all :)  - I have switched over to getting sharing to work to see if it is just this or if i can't get cordova to work at all.  I have gotten twitter & FB sharing happening & am finishing up downloading images to the gallery then back on to this.  Good news is i do have some cordova plugins working.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Adam but I have not been able to get it working in the simulator.  I shall try again when i have signed up to the apple dev program. Comments in the ionic examples saying the plugin is "broken" are not encouraging.

Comment: Cordova/phonegap is great because it's open-source. Cordova/phonegap can be frustrating because it's open-source. ;-). Sorry I wasn't able to trouble-shoot with you.